# an adjective "special" and articles with uncountable nouns

Tags: word-meaning, articles, vocabulary

I've heard that an uncountable noun turns to be countable if it's used with a word "special".　Is that true？

> "I will make you **a** special **dinner**."

My dictionary says "dinner" can be both countable and uncountable, but countable "dinner" means the dinner in a party.

Can "dinner" in the sentence above mean the ordinary but great dinner between two people or does it always mean a special meal for a party?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would agree that adding "special" can make a non-count noun into a count noun, but it isn't the only way that can happen.

For example:

> **A:** I was just about to make something. Have you had dinner yet?
> **B:** I did eat earlier, but I can have two dinners today!

A's "dinner" is a non-count noun, but by specifically referencing the meals which they had and will eat, B turned their "dinner" into a count noun.

Comment: Wow, that's interesting!  Can I ask you further?  Is there any case where non-count noun remains uncountable after "special"? If so, could you tell me how you distinguish their article in usage?

Comment: _I want you to take special care of this fragile glassware._ That is, to be especially careful when you handle it.

Comment: @KateBunting Oh! I think I understand a little further about "special" and articles.  Maybe I should read more English and find many examples to understand it. Thank you!